# Should I delete variables I don't plan on using anymore?

Tags: python-3.x, data-cleaning

At first, it sounds like a no-brainer, but the more I think about it the more I feel like others' opinions would be helpful. Whenever looking at others' Python code, I never see them delete variables. Is there a reason for this, or is it just them not wanting to. I assume it has to do more with clean code vs. quick code, but I'm not sure that's the case. Plus, to be honest, I don't know for sure the impact deleting variables has on a program (I always just assumed it was good, since the courses I've taken on Python never really mentioned it).

Example of deleting a variable...

```
j = 'jjjjj'
for i in range(len(j)):
    print(j[i], j)
del j
```

Not the most relatable example but you get the point.

Comment: You almost never would have to, if your code is well organized into functions/classes/methods

Comment: Depends on the programming environment. Jupyter Notebook / Lab are **terrible** at garbage collection.

Comment: If you're concerned about the amount of space used by objects, consider learning a about `generators`.  For example `k = ('j' for _ in range(1000000))` is 120 bytes, but `l = list(k)` is 8250168 bytes. `type(k)` is `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000002B4C8FB23C8>` and `type(l)` is `list`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, don't worry about deleting variables.

Python has [garbage collection](https://stackify.com/python-garbage-collection/), so any objects that you can no longer access (usually because you've left their scope) will automatically be freed from memory, you don't have to worry about this at all.

The case where you might want to use `del` would be if you want to make it *explicity clear* that this variable cannot be used anymore by this part of the program.

As mentioned in the comments, this won't even necessarily delete your object.

You can read about the `del` keyword more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement)

Comment: Well, *variables* aren't freed, objects are

Comment: Yes. Python does have variables... variables refer to objects. `del` deletes variables, but not objects (although a reference count reaching zero could result in an object being freed). They are definitely not interchangeable

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I see, that makes sense, I'll edit my answer accordingly